# Como fazer ordenação com LINQ com uma LIST<T> dentro de outra?

Tags: c#, linq

Aparentemente fácil mas não estou conseguindo fazer um LINQ que ordene duas LIST que estão aninhadas. Não sei se a palavra "aninhadas" é o correto.

Como posso fazer essa ordenação através do LINQ, no codigo abaixo apresento o local onde desejo fazer o LINQ.

**Resultado Atual**

```
/*
 * Grupo um
 *    Item1
 *    Item3
 *    Item2
 * Grupo dois
 *    Item6
 *    Item4
 *    Item5               
 */
```

**Resultado Pretendido:**

```
/*
 * Grupo dois
 *    Item4
 *    Item5
 *    Item6
 * Grupo um
 *    Item1
 *    Item2
 *    Item3               
 */
```

**Segue o código completo:**

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Combo combo = CarregarCombo();

            //Tentei essas linhas abaixo mas estão com erro:
            // Desejo fazer o LINQ no lugar dessas linhas para que eu possa fazer o foreach na LIST ordenada:

            Combo cboTeste1 = new Combo(); 
            Combo cboTeste2 = new Combo();

            cboTeste1.Grupos = combo.Grupos.OrderByDescending(g => g.Key && g.Itens.OrderBy(i => i.Value));
            cboTeste2.Grupos = combo.Grupos.OrderByDescending(g => g.Key).ToList().ForEach(g => g.Itens.OrderBy(i => i.Value)));

            foreach (var grupo in combo.Grupos) //Trocar aqui para usar cboTeste1.Grupos ou cboTeste2.Grupos
            {
                Console.WriteLine(grupo.Text);

                foreach (var item in grupo.Itens)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" " + item.Text);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static Combo CarregarCombo()
        {
            Grupo grupo1 = new Grupo();
            grupo1.Text = "Grupo um";
            grupo1.Key = "1";
            grupo1.Itens = new List<Item>();

            Item item1 = new Item();
            item1.Text = "Item1";
            item1.Value = "1";
            grupo1.Itens.Add(item1);

            Item item3 = new Item();
            item3.Text = "Item3";
            item3.Value = "3";
            grupo1.Itens.Add(item3);

            Item item2 = new Item();
            item2.Text = "Item2";
            item2.Value = "2";
            grupo1.Itens.Add(item2);

            Grupo grupo2 = new Grupo();
            grupo2.Text = "Grupo dois";
            grupo1.Key = "2";
            grupo2.Itens = new List<Item>();

            Item item6 = new Item();
            item6.Text = "Item6";
            item6.Value = "6";  
            grupo2.Itens.Add(item6);

            Item item4 = new Item();
            item4.Text = "Item4";
            item4.Value = "4";
            grupo2.Itens.Add(item4);

            Item item5 = new Item();
            item5.Text = "Item5";
            item5.Value = "5";
            grupo2.Itens.Add(item5);

            Combo combo = new Combo();
            combo.Grupos = new List<Grupo>();
            combo.Grupos.Add(grupo1);
            combo.Grupos.Add(grupo2);

            return combo;
        }
    }

    public class Combo
    {
        public List<Grupo> Grupos { get; set; }
    }

    public class Grupo
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public List<Item> Itens { get; set; }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public bool Selected { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Exemplo:***

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Combo combo = CarregarCombo();

    //ordenando os grupos.        
    combo.Grupos = combo.Grupos.OrderBy(o => o.Key).ToList();

    //ordenando e atribuindo a mesma variavel Itens
    combo.Grupos.ForEach(c =>
    {
        c.Itens = c.Itens.OrderBy(d => d.Value).ToList();
    });  

    foreach (var grupo in combo.Grupos)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(grupo.Text);

        foreach (var item in grupo.Itens.OrderBy(c => c.Value))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" " + item.Text);
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

<sub>**Observação:** Essas duas ordenação, talvez precise de um ajuste no campo `Value` que em vez de ser um `int`, está como `string` e pesquisas maiores pode haver problemas. Outro ponto, se precisar de vários tipos de ordenação da mesma lista é só atribuir os novos valores em novas variáveis.</sub>

Comment: Eu criei o exemplo em uma aplicação a parte permitindo usar o grupo.Itens.OrderBy(c => c.Value)), na aplicação real eu não posso fazer nem no orderby do select nem da forma que você colocou a cima pq vou usar esse resultado em mais de um lugar sendo que algumas vezes via JSON.

Comment: @MauricioFerraz porque?

Comment: Gostaria de tudo em um único LINQ, você consegue? |Na verdade nem sei se é possível mas creio que sim rsrs. De qualquer forma muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Você quer @MauricioFerraz nessas duas linhas  `combo.Grupos.OrderByDescending(g => g.Key).ToList();` ?

Comment: Quero que em um único LINQ (uma linha) ele ordene as duas listas de uma vez.

Comment: @MauricioFerraz fiz de outra forma vê se é isso?

Comment: Editado @MauricioFerraz....

Comment: Esse código dos dois LINQs que você colocou resolveu meu problema, eu não sei se tem como fazer em um só mas o seu resolve perfeitamente meu problema. Muito obrigado. Sobre o campo ser string ele era int mas para o meu caso eu achei melhor usar string e não vou ter problemas com isso. De qualquer forma obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 3):

Não entendi muito bem a sua dúvida, mas não basta ordenar o retorno?

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Combo combo = CarregarCombo();

        foreach (var grupo in combo.Grupos.OrderBy(g => g.Key))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(grupo.Text);

            foreach (var item in grupo.Itens.OrderBy(c => c.Value))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" " + item.Text);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

[Veja um exemplo funcional no Ideone.](http://ideone.com/s5OpaW)

Comment: Em uma das partes do sistema eu uso uma requisição $.ajax e pego o retorno no formato JSON e depois e depois percorro o grupo e item com o $.each, por isso eu queria já trazer os dados ordenados. Obrigado.

Comment: @MauricioFerraz Você traz esses dados do banco de dados?

Comment: @Sim e não, eu trago alguns dados do banco e depois faço um tipo merge (manual) neles em cima de dados fixo que estão no código para gerar meus dados que são usados para alimentar o combo.Grupos.Obrigado por sua ajuda a duvida era mesmos saber apenas se tinha uma forma de fazer somente com um LINQ.